# Load vendor dependencies with composer.json

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I have recently forked robmorgan/phinx project and modified the composer.json file in my project to use the forked version:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "lube8uy/phinx",
        "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/lube8uy/phinx.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "lube8uy/phinx": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

**First question: additional vendors**

Now, when I load the composer.json file in my project I get this forked version correctly. 
What I don't know is how to load the dependencies from the phinx project itself:
https://github.com/lube8uy/phinx/blob/master/composer.json

If I use the original packagist source everything works fine and I got all the dependencies, but now that I use my own repository I can't get them.

**Second question: updates**

How can I receive the modifications I made to my github source?
I made some modifications, pushed them to the correct branch, then I run composer update but nothing was updated... what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is composer showing any error message or does it just ignore the dependencies of the forked version? Composer normally fetches every `composer.json` available and then decides which version of a given package to install.

Comment: Hi, it's just ignoring it. After making a composer download it downloads only the thing in the lube8uy repo.

Comment: +1, interesting and useful question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your first question:**

Try to require it as a VCS repository (Version Control System, see [composer doc on vcs repositories](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)), like the following:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/lube8uy/phinx"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

It now requires the package `robmorgan/phinx` which is found at `https://github.com/lube8uy/phinx` which is the desired fork. It still has the original name `robmorgan/phinx` but is found at a different location.

It still has the same name because of the package name in its `composer.json`. If you want to change the name to `lube8ye/phinx`, change it in the `composer.json` in the fork.

**For your second question:**

The changes made in a package you require via composer should be updated automatically when you execute `php composer.phar update` in your project. If this does not work, try to force composer to require a specific commit by adding the commit hash after `dev-master` in your `require` section like so:

```
    "require": {
        "robmorgan/phinx": "dev-master#1234abcd"
    }
```

Whereat `1234abcd` is the hash of the desired commit.

Also: Try clearing composer's cache by deleting the folders content to avoid loading a cached version (see [composer doc on `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-cache-dir))